# Align tables to each others side

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have created two tables with bootstrap 4, which show on the one hand specifications and on the other hand earning statistics.

I put both tables in a `col-xs-6`-class and want one table aligned to the left and the other table to the right. However, currently the tables are somehow *clued* to each other. Please find below my minimum viable example:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <h2>Specifications</h2>
    <table class="table stats">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>Price :</th>
          <td class=" text-right">
            100 </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Manufacturer:</th>
          <td class=" text-right">
            Gigabyte </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Wattage:</th>
          <td class=" text-right">
            150 </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Product:</th>
          <td class=" text-right">
            Product 1 </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <h2>Earning</h2>
    <table class="table stats">
      <tbody>
      </tbody>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Period</th>
          <th class="text-right">Rev</th>
          <th class="text-right">Cost</th>
          <th class="text-right">Profit</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Hour</td>
          <td class="text-right text-info">$
            <span id="rev-hour">
                          0.022                        </span>
          </td>
          <td class="text-right text-danger">$
            <span id="cost-hour">
                          0.006                        </span>
          </td>
          <td class="text-right text-success">$
            <span id="earning-hour">
                          0.016                        </span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Day</td>
          <td class="text-right text-info">$
            <span id="rev-day">
                          1.34                        </span>
          </td>
          <td class="text-right text-danger">$
            <span id="cost-day">
                          0.36                        </span>
          </td>
          <td class="text-right text-success">$
            <span id="earning-day">
                          0.98                        </span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Week</td>
          <td class="text-right text-info">$
            <span id="rev-week">
                          9.37                        </span>
          </td>
          <td class="text-right text-danger">$
            <span id="cost-week">
                          2.52                        </span>
          </td>
          <td class="text-right text-success">$
            <span id="earning-week">
                          6.85                        </span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Month</td>
          <td class="text-right text-info">$
            <span id="rev-month">
                          37.48                        </span>
          </td>
          <td class="text-right text-danger">$
            <span id="cost-month">
                          10.08                        </span>
          </td>
          <td class="text-right text-success">$
            <span id="earning-month">
                          27.40                        </span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Year</td>
          <td class="text-right text-info">$
            <span id="rev-year">
                          449.77                        </span>
          </td>
          <td class="text-right text-danger">$
            <span id="cost-year">
                          120.96                        </span>
          </td>
          <td class="text-right text-success">$
            <span id="earning-year">
                          328.81                        </span>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any suggestions how to align the `Specification` table to the left and the `Earnings` table to the right?

I appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `container-fluid` class div around the row.
There is no such class as `col-xs-6` instead use `col-6`

Added another div in `col-6` and add padding to it for making some space between them.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="pr-1">
        <h2>Specifications</h2>
        <table class="table stats">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th>Price :</th>
              <td class=" text-right">
                100 </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>Manufacturer:</th>
              <td class=" text-right">
                Gigabyte </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>Wattage:</th>
              <td class=" text-right">
                150 </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>Product:</th>
              <td class=" text-right">
                Product 1 </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="pr-1">
        <h2>Earning</h2>
        <table class="table stats">
          <tbody>
          </tbody>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Period</th>
              <th class="text-right">Rev</th>
              <th class="text-right">Cost</th>
              <th class="text-right">Profit</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Hour</td>
              <td class="text-right text-info">$
                <span id="rev-hour">
                            0.022                        </span>
              </td>
              <td class="text-right text-danger">$
                <span id="cost-hour">
                            0.006                        </span>
              </td>
              <td class="text-right text-success">$
                <span id="earning-hour">
                            0.016                        </span>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Day</td>
              <td class="text-right text-info">$
                <span id="rev-day">
                            1.34                        </span>
              </td>
              <td class="text-right text-danger">$
                <span id="cost-day">
                            0.36                        </span>
              </td>
              <td class="text-right text-success">$
                <span id="earning-day">
                            0.98                        </span>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Week</td>
              <td class="text-right text-info">$
                <span id="rev-week">
                            9.37                        </span>
              </td>
              <td class="text-right text-danger">$
                <span id="cost-week">
                            2.52                        </span>
              </td>
              <td class="text-right text-success">$
                <span id="earning-week">
                            6.85                        </span>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Month</td>
              <td class="text-right text-info">$
                <span id="rev-month">
                            37.48                        </span>
              </td>
              <td class="text-right text-danger">$
                <span id="cost-month">
                            10.08                        </span>
              </td>
              <td class="text-right text-success">$
                <span id="earning-month">
                            27.40                        </span>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Year</td>
              <td class="text-right text-info">$
                <span id="rev-year">
                            449.77                        </span>
              </td>
              <td class="text-right text-danger">$
                <span id="cost-year">
                            120.96                        </span>
              </td>
              <td class="text-right text-success">$
                <span id="earning-year">
                            328.81                        </span>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

One ruleset:

```
table.table.stats {display:inline-table}
```

**[`display: inline-table`](https://www.brunildo.org/test/inline-block2.html)** behavior is simply a table that will sit inline with elements instead of the default behavior of occupying the whole width and pushing everything at its left and right -- up and down.

you might have a more complicated environment with your real code so you can
[Chain the classes](https://css-tricks.com/multiple-class-id-selectors/) to get higher **[specificity](https://specificity.keegan.st/)**  which may be overkill but with Bootstrap it is common necessity.

```
table.table.stats.table.stats {display:inline-table}
```

---

### Demo

```css
table.table.stats {
  display: inline-table
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <h2>Specifications</h2>
    <table class="table stats">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>Price :</th>
          <td class=" text-right">
            100 </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Manufacturer:</th>
          <td class=" text-right">
            Gigabyte </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Wattage:</th>
          <td class=" text-right">
            150 </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Product:</th>
          <td class=" text-right">
            Product 1 </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <h2>Earning</h2>
    <table class="table stats">
      <tbody>
      </tbody>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Period</th>
          <th class="text-right">Rev</th>
          <th class="text-right">Cost</th>
          <th class="text-right">Profit</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Hour</td>
          <td class="text-right text-info">$
            <span id="rev-hour">
                          0.022                        </span>
          </td>
          <td class="text-right text-danger">$
            <span id="cost-hour">
                          0.006                        </span>
          </td>
          <td class="text-right text-success">$
            <span id="earning-hour">
                          0.016                        </span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Day</td>
          <td class="text-right text-info">$
            <span id="rev-day">
                          1.34                        </span>
          </td>
          <td class="text-right text-danger">$
            <span id="cost-day">
                          0.36                        </span>
          </td>
          <td class="text-right text-success">$
            <span id="earning-day">
                          0.98                        </span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Week</td>
          <td class="text-right text-info">$
            <span id="rev-week">
                          9.37                        </span>
          </td>
          <td class="text-right text-danger">$
            <span id="cost-week">
                          2.52                        </span>
          </td>
          <td class="text-right text-success">$
            <span id="earning-week">
                          6.85                        </span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Month</td>
          <td class="text-right text-info">$
            <span id="rev-month">
                          37.48                        </span>
          </td>
          <td class="text-right text-danger">$
            <span id="cost-month">
                          10.08                        </span>
          </td>
          <td class="text-right text-success">$
            <span id="earning-month">
                          27.40                        </span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Year</td>
          <td class="text-right text-info">$
            <span id="rev-year">
                          449.77                        </span>
          </td>
          <td class="text-right text-danger">$
            <span id="cost-year">
                          120.96                        </span>
          </td>
          <td class="text-right text-success">$
            <span id="earning-year">
                          328.81                        </span>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```